# asp.net mvc post action post nothing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

my action method:

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [RequiredPermissions(RequiredPermissionName, Operation.Delete)]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(User userWhoGone)
    {
        _db.Users.Remove(userWhoGone);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        this.TempData["msg"] = "Deleted User Id " + userWhoGone.Id;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Delete.cshtml

```
@model NewsMonitoringWeb.Database.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Delete";

<h2>User Delete</h2>
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this user?</h3>

@Html.Partial("_PartialUser")

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

_PartialUser.cshtml

```
@model NewsMonitoringWeb.Database.Models.User

<fieldset>
    <legend>User</legend>

    <div class="display-label">User Role</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.UserRole.Name)

    </div>

    <div class="display-label">FirstName</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">LastName</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Email</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">Is Contributor</div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.IsContributor)
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

i use chrome to check the posted data, and i found that this method **post nothing** to server.

any suggestion?

Comment: You may need to provide the view's markup...

Comment: Are you have issues posting to the method? Can you show us the form code that is doing the posting and how does the User parameter gets resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has no values to post back.  You need to either put some hidden input values in your form to build the user or add a hidden user id to the form and change the post action method.

The later would be my preferred method as follows:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[RequiredPermissions(RequiredPermissionName, Operation.Delete)]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int userIdWhoGone)
{

    _db.Users.RemoveById(userIdWhoGone); // You may need to create this.
    // Atlernatively, get the user by id then call 'Remove()
    var user = _db.User.Find(userIdWhoGone);
    _db.Users.Remove(user);


    _db.SaveChanges();

    this.TempData["msg"] = "Deleted User Id " + userIdWhoGone;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Delete.cshtml

```
@model NewsMonitoringWeb.Database.Models.User
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Delete";

<h2>User Delete</h2>
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this user?</h3>

@Html.Partial("_PartialUser")

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <p>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id) @* <--- New input *@
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </p>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not currently posting anything back at all. Your user partial is outside the form.

The only thing in the form is your button and a link.

You need to move your partial so that it is inside the form.

So it will now look like this:

```
@model NewsMonitoringWeb.Database.Models.User
@{
ViewBag.Title = "User Delete";

<h2>User Delete</h2>
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this user?</h3>



@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.Partial("_PartialUser")    
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
}
```

EDIT

You will need to either add a hidden input to the partial containing the User ID or leave the partial where it was and just put a hidden input within the form.

You would then need change the action to accept the userid and do a lookup on the database.

Comment: This will not work as the partial view only has display elements.